# Coordinate descent on non-continuous functions

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, nonlinear

The typical coordinate descent (CD) algorithm uses the gradient along each coordinate, or along some hyperplane obtained from a group of coordinates, to find the minimizer along that direction. My question is, does requiring the gradient imply that CD cannot be applied to non-continuous and non-smooth functions? I mean, in the general formulation shown below, there is no limitation on how to obtain the minimizer along a direction. It can, for example, be using a clever search method:

[image]

By the way, I'm aware of some special cases where non-smoothness is separable. I'm interested to see if there is any extension to coordinate descent that can handle more general functions, albeit less efficiently and without convergence proofs.

Comment: Exactly how would you apply any form of "coordinate descent" when a gradient is unavailable?

Comment: @whuber: Well, a crude example would be to test some values for y in the above equation and choose the one that minimizes _f_. In some applications, there might actually be a finite set of possible values for y to check.

Comment: You haven't described any kind of "coordinate descent" algorithm: that's just a brute-force search.

Comment: @whuber: It may not be coordinate "descent", but it is search along coordinates, and I want it to use an algorithm similar to CD. It would be more like a heuristic than full brute-force, because the solution space we check depends on the set of possible values we check for y.

Comment: When the objective function is discontinuous, what heuristic could possibly work?

Comment: @whuber: If you only check a set of possible values for y at every iteration (say for example), it won't matter if _f_ is continuous or not (or even defined everywhere).

Comment: It matters *tremendously*!  If $f$ is not continuous, and you make no other assumptions about it, then what you learn from its value at one point tells you nothing whatsoever about its values anywhere else.

Comment: @whuber: I see your point, but what if we have "some" assumptions. For example if the function has one global optimum and no local optima.

Comment: You're headed in the right direction, but that assumption is far too weak to do much with.  Please decide what your problem really is and what assumptions you really can make about $f$, and tell us what they are in your question.  Otherwise, as it is currently posed, we will have to consider it to be too broad to be answerable.

Comment: @whuber: I really do not intend to narrow it to a specific application.Any "example" of an extension of the CD algorithm to functions beyond continuous will do.

Answer (score 2):

To rephrase your question, you are basically asking if you can optimize a black-box function in some way (without any guarantees on what that function is). There is lots of literature out there about hyperparameter optimization, which essentially tries to create some kind of function or prior on a set of input parameters that optimizes some black box function.

Here is an overview paper from NIPS a few years back that addresses some general approaches: http://papers.nips.cc/paper/4443-algorithms-for-hyper-parameter-optimization.pdf

An example of a software package that can do this kind of optimization is [HPOlib](http://www.automl.org/hpolib.html), which combines a few of the techniques mentioned in the paper above from various other sources.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but what I meant was an extension of coordinate descent that can be applied to a function with slightly higher relaxations. For example one that is convex but has non-continuity.

Comment: A more philosophical question perhaps is why use coordinate descent when something like bayesopt is available for generalized black-box functions?

Answer (score 1):

If the function is convex but non-smooth, you can still use CD to get to a global optimum. An example is the CD algorithm for [lasso](https://www.google.it/urlhttps://www.google.it/url?q=https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ggordon/10725-F12/slides/25-coord-desc.pdf&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwiWlf-C967LAhVHjQ8KHeDxDmcQFggQMAA&sig2=RD4PNyExSo2-QiYsC1FQmg&usg=AFQjCNE8llakTPflW0YuPH21w_VY4ebUqg).

If your function is discreete, you don't have any guarantee that e.g. minimizing along each dimension you get to a global optimum.

Comment: True, we won't have a guarantee, but is there an algorithm/heuristic out there that let's us approximate the optimal for such cases using the basic idea of CD?

Comment: Using CD in these cases you will probably get stuck in local optima

Comment: Yes, otherwise you would have a black-box optimization algorithm in your hands. However, there are search-based algorithms (like Genetic Algorithm) out there that can produce good results, but in most cases without guarantees.

Comment: Maybe you can get something that works mixing CD with simulated annealing. But again, if your objective is convex but non-smooth you can still get to the global best only with CD. If the objective is not even continuous, you can still get something, but I'm afraid it will be problem-dependent.